# Migrating from armcc to armclang causes section type conflict

Tags: c, compiler-errors, arm, embedded, clang

Since ARM Keil µVision has changed their default compiler from `armcc` to `armclang`, I am trying to migrate an existing project. Most of the new errors generated by simply switching the compiler have been easily cleaned up with help from their migration guides. But I cannot seem to fix the following error:

```
Display/icons.c(54): error: 'iconBitMapArray' causes a section type conflict with 'pNULL'
XRAM_VAR GUI_CONST_STORAGE  GUI_BITMAP *iconBitMapArray[] =  // bitmaps for icons
                                        ^
Display/icons.c(44): note: declared here
XRAM_VAR GUI_CONST_STORAGE GUI_BITMAP pNULL =  // used for returning a pointer to a NULL image
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
#define XRAM_VAR                __attribute__((section("XRAM_DATA")))

XRAM_VAR uint32_t icon_status_internal;
XRAM_VAR GUI_CONST_STORAGE GUI_BITMAP pNULL =  // used for returning a pointer to a NULL image
{
    0, /* XSize */
    0, /* YSize */
    0, /* BytesPerLine */
    0, /* BitsPerPixel */
    0, /* Pointer to picture data (indices) */
    0  /* Pointer to palette */
};

XRAM_VAR GUI_CONST_STORAGE GUI_BITMAP *iconBitMapArray[] =  // bitmaps for icons
{
        &pNULL,
        &bmIcon1,
        &bmIcon2,
        // ...etc.
};
```

The variable `icon_status_internal` also causes the same error.

There are several similar questions on here and the error seems to come from trying to place zero initialized data into the same section as data that is initialized to non-zero values. The flag, `-fno-zero-initialized-in-bss` is mentioned a lot. I tried adding that to the compiler string and the linker string but that did not help.

On page 8 of the [migration guide](http://www.keil.com/appnotes/files/apnt_298.pdf), there are two possible solutions they suggest when using Link-Time Optimization (LTO). We are not using LTO but I tried them both anyways. I tried changing the memory assignment from default to our external RAM.

[image: memory assignment]

This also did not help. The other suggestion was to add the section name to the scatter file which was already there.

```
; Just the variables declared using __attribute__((section("XRAM_DATA")))
  RW_XRAM1 0x70000000 0x00010000  {  ; External Ram
   *.o(XRAM_DATA)
  }
```

When using `armcc` the variables are placed in a `Data` type section in the section labeled "XRAM_DATA" without any special compiler options as can be seen in the `.map` file:

```
pNULL                                    0x70000000   Data          20  icons.o(XRAM_DATA)
icon_status_internal                     0x70000014   Data           4  icons.o(XRAM_DATA)
iconBitMapArray                          0x70000018   Data         352  icons.o(XRAM_DATA)
```

How do I get all of these variables to be placed in a `Data` type section in my external RAM when using `armclang` like `armcc` did? Are there any other workarounds that I can try? Do I need to create seperate `bss` and `data` sections in my external RAM? What else can I try?

Comment: The `icon_status_internal` is an uninitialized variable (.bss), `pNULL` and `iconBitMapArray` are initialized variables (.data).  .bss data is placed in memory which is just cleared,  .data is placed in a memory part, where usually a copytable is used to initialize them. There might be another question about the `GUI_CONST_STORAGE`, whatever is created by this (e.g. const?).

Comment: @kesselhaus I understand that normally these variables would be placed in different type sections. But this should be controllable with `__attribute__` or `-fno-zero-initialized-in-bss`. I guess the main question is how do I get all of these variables to be placed in a `Data` type section in my external RAM? And as far as I can tell, `GUI_CONST_STORAGE` is just defined as `const`.

Comment: But, the GUI_CONST_STORAGE might exactly be the problem, since this tells compilers especially for embedded to place them not in .bss or .data, but in .text or .rodata.